# CSS: floating images by odd/even order inside a container

Tags: html, css, image, css-selectors, css-float

I have images in a text. The images are put into `<p>` tags and occasionally into `<div>` tags. The whole text is inside `<article>` tag like this:

```
<article>
<h1>Title</h1>
<p><img src="picture1.jpg"> Text...</p>
<p><img src="picture2.jpg"> Text...</p>
</article>
```

What I would like to achieve is to float odd images to the left and even images to the right. I tried this:

```
 article img:nth-of-type(odd) {
 float:left;
 }
 article img:nth-of-type(even) {
 float:right;
 }
```

But since the :nth-* selectors checks the element relatively to its very direct parent - in my case `<p>` or `<div>`, the images always result to be the first childs of type `<img>` of its parents, so the odd style (floating to the left) is always applied. How do I do this trick - selecting `<img>` tags relatively to the `<article>` tag - properly without changing the markup?

PS. I could apply :nth-* selector to `<p>`-s, but in this case the images become unrelated to the `<article>` and only the `<p>`-s' order matters which results in both images floated to one side if their respective `<p>`-s are both odd or both even under `<article>`. I hope you get the idea. Maybe I am stuck with a silly/simple issue but I cannot figure it out :(

Comment: `p:nth-of-type(odd)`?

Comment: I think you need smth like `article p:nth-of-type(odd)  image{float:left}` and `article p:nth-of-type(even) image{float:right}`

Comment: You are **definitely** right with your thinking of `p:nth-of-type`. How can you have two `<p>` elements that are both odd? How are your paragraphs getting generated? Shouldn't it generate odd, even, odd, even, etc.?

Comment: yeah, I thought about it. But what if the paragraphs containing images are both odd or both even? The images get floated to one side.

Comment: I mean images can be inside any paragraphs - 1st and third or second and fourth - there are paragraphs without images - it is totally random and depends on a person who edits the text in the CMS. I have just a flow of paragraphs that form the article. The goal is to float images in odd/even order, not paragraphs.

Comment: I see your difficulty now. If you have access to jQuery, you could check the **contents** of the `<p>` tag before you apply the styling, with `.has()`.

Comment: yes, JS is always an option but I would like to get it sorted out without resorting to JS. Looking for a pure css solution.

Comment: Sadly, there is no parent selector in CSS, which is what you would need.

Comment: so, JS is the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a way to achieve this using CSS.

But the javascript + CSS approach is fairly straightforward:

**CSS**

```
article img.even {
float: right;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var article = document.getElementsByTagName('article')[0];
var articleImages = article.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i = 1; i < articleImages.length; i = i + 2) {
    articleImages[i].classList.add('even');
}
```